# Rails Simple Form Radio_buttons: How to add different class for diffent radio input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, simple-form

I use simple_form in Rails, and I want to add different class for different radio input. I did some search, but no luck.

Here is a example:

**Views**

```
<%= f.label "Gift Pack?" %><br>

<%= f.input :gift_pack, as: :radio_buttons,
        :collection => [[true, 'Gift Pack'], [false, 'Original Pack']],
        label: false,
        :label_method => :last,
        :value_method => :first,
        :input_html => { :class => 'gift_pack gift_pack_yes' } %>
```

**Generated HTML**

```
<input class="radio_buttons optional gift_pack gift_pack_yes" type="radio" value="true" name="book[gift_pack]" id="book_gift_pack_true"> Gift Pack

<input class="radio_buttons optional gift_pack gift_pack_yes" type="radio" value="false" name="book[gift_pack]" id="book_gift_pack_false"> Original Pack -->
```

**Want to**

HOW to make the second input's class is `radio_buttons optional gift_pack gift_pack_no` , Notice the last class is `gift_pack_no` .

Thanks.

Comment: for this case you need to create view helper in which you need to pass id and based on that id you need to assign `class`

Comment: @uzaif Thank you for your reply. Could you show me the detail in a answer, and I can accept it as Answer.

Comment: please check my answer let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first create new view helper

## helper

```
def gift_radio_class(val)
  val ? "gift_pack_yes" : " gift_pack_no"
end
```

in Your erb you have to call above helper

## erb

```
<%=f.collection_radio_buttons(:gift_val, [[true, 'Gift Pack'], [false, 'Original Pack']], :first,:second) do |b|%>
<%b.label{ b.radio_button(class: gift_radio_class(b.value)) + b.text }%>
  <%end %>
```

we can retrieve class name based on boolen value of check box via view helper function `gift_radio_class`

check out docs if you need more custom solution http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:collection_radio_buttons

Comment: awesome, it's very good. Thank you very much. 

What does mean of `:"data-value` ?

Comment: its data attribute check out your label tag in html

Comment: yes, I can found it in chrome dev tools. But I don't understand why use `:"data-value` ? There are no this data attribut when I use `<%= f.input :gift_pack, as: :radio_buttons ....` .

Comment: please check updated answer in which i remove `data-value`  for accessing
 collection object value i used `collection_radio_buttons`

Comment: Hi @uzaif , now everything is good except for there are duplicate `<label for="registration_is_room_share_false">` . The complete code is:

`<span><label for="registration_is_room_share_false"><label for="registration_is_room_share_false"><input class="radio_buttons optional room_share room_share_no" type="radio" value="false" checked="checked" name="registration[is_room_share]" id="registration_is_room_share_false">Share</label></label></span>`

Comment: Now it's OK, after I added `boolean_style: :inline` into `collection_radio_buttons`.